# React Native Sourcemaps - Wrong Files

Tags: javascript, babeljs, react-native

When I remote-debug in Chrome, the files are all wrong. Open a source file, and it's not the file it claims to be.

e.g....

- Open `common/BaseComponent.js` and you get the source is for
  `native/components/logGraph.js`.
- Open
  `native/components/logGraph.js` and you get the source for
  `native/actions/driverActions.js`.
- And so on, no apparent rhyme or reason.

Even when I find the "right" file, breakpoints are not hit.

Then...switch to some certain older branch, the problem is goes away. This tells me there's something specific in my code that react-native is tripping over.

I'm lost as to how to even troubleshoot this. If anyone else is having this problem, I can't find it on the Interwebs.

Suggestions?

In case it's relevant, we're using Genymotion for emulation. We're on react-native 0.26. My parter is working on getting us to 0.30-rc to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I've been having the same kinds of issues for a while now. Using es6, decorators syntax, jsx etc. Any luck with this one?

Comment: @Marc - This stopped happening somewhere along the way. I assume it was an upgrade it react or react-native, but we never did pinpoint it.